# Não entendo pq não mostra todos os primos neste intervalo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eh_primo(int x){
    int i;
    int cont;
    for (i=1;i<=x;i++){
        if (x % i == 0){
          cont +=1;
        }
    }
    if (cont == 2 || cont == 1){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}

void todos_os_primos(int max){
  int j;
  for (j=1;j<=max;j++){
    if(eh_primo(j) == 1){
      printf("%d",j);
    }else{}
  }

}


int main (void){
    int n;
    printf("Digite o numero: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    todos_os_primos(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quanto valerá `cont += 1` se você não conhece o valor de `cont`? Vale lembrar que o número 1 não é primo.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você inicializar `cont=0` na função `eh_primo`

```
int eh_primo(int x){
    int i;
    int cont =0 ;
    for (i=1;i<=x;i++){
        if (x % i == 0){
          cont +=1;
        }
    }
    if (cont == 2 || cont == 1){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Mas tenha em mente que você pode fazer outras melhorias em seu código.

1. Você não precisa verificar a divisão por 1 (todo número é divisível por 1, logo não é preciso)
2. Você pode fazer a comparação do resto da divisão `x % i == 0 && x != i` já te dá um número que não é primo e você já pode retorná-lo.

Comment: Otimização por otimização você poderia iterar por absurdamente menos números

Comment: Sim. Dá pra fazer otimizações. Só não quis modificar o código dele